# How to check Post is shared successfully on Google Plus

Tags: android, google-plus

```
@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{  
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if(requestCode==392 &&resultCode==RESULT_OK)
     { 
          System.out.println("Google+"); 
     } 
}

Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getActivity())
            .setText(". http://www.http://stackoverflow.com/")
            .setType("text/plain")
            .getIntent()
            .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

            startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 392);
```

I want to check if it is posted or not, How to check if user posted successfully or cancelled the Sharing.

Comment: I guess you could override `onActivityResult()` and listen for `RESULT_OK` and `RESULT_CANCELED`.

Comment: @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         if(requestCode==392 &&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
         System.out.println("Google+"); 
         }

}